# bootstrap-table max(min) value on the column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table, max, min, bootstrap-table

In bootstrap-table, how can I do so, that the max(min) value in column Item Price can change it's color

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="table" data-toggle="table">
   <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
                <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>first</td> <td>5.4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>second</td><td>7.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>third</td><td>2.1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>thourth</td><td>7.8</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: will you please elaborate? what you want to do with table column?

Answer (score 2):

you can do with Javascript :

```
op=0;
var max = 0;
$('.price').each(function(i, obj) {
     $this = parseFloat( $(this).text() );
      if ($this > max) {
         max = $this;
         op = i;
                       }
 });

var all = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
 all[op].style.color = 'red';
```

and you can edit your html :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="table" data-toggle="table">
   <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
                <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>first</td> <td class="price">5.4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>second</td><td class="price">10.2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>third</td><td class="price">12.3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>thourth</td><td class="price">7.8</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gja068xe/4/)**

Comment: As soon as i sort the column, the color disapears, and also when there are two items with maximum values, it changes the color for only one item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [post-body.bs.table event](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#events) and on document ready and on post-body event you can:

- sort your table
- filter by max or min
- set your favorite color

```js
function styleMaxMin(isMax) {
    isMax = isMax == undefined ? true : isMax;
    var sortedTbl =
           $('#table tbody td:last-child').sort(isMax ?
                   (a, b) => {return +b.textContent - +a.textContent} :
                   (a, b) => {return +a.textContent - +b.textContent});
    sortedTbl.filter(function (idx, ele) {
        var currVal = +ele.textContent;
        return currVal == +sortedTbl.eq(0).text();
    }).css('color', 'red');
}

$(function () {
    styleMaxMin();
    $('#table').on('post-body.bs.table', function (e, data) {
        styleMaxMin();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table id="table" data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
        <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>5.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>7.8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>third</td>
        <td>2.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>thourth</td>
        <td>7.8</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks a lot for your help.                                                                       1. this code shows error on internet explorer.                                                    2. If I have several columns, I want the max value to be shown in all columns, not only in one of them, can you please help me in this issue?